# Error popover bootstrap solo funciona al presionarse por segunda vez

Tags: java, javascript, jquery, ajax, bootstrap

Por qué razón al presionar una imagen que muestra un popOver Bootstrap, este 
solo se despliega cuando la imagen que lo invoca se presiona por segunda vez, siempre que se haga click nuevamente sobre la imagen debo presionar 
dos veces para que se muestre el popOver.

Etiqueta de imagen que redirecciona a una funcion en javascript:

```
<img src=...  alt=... id="popoverUser1" name="1" onclick="consultaPerfil(this.name)" >
```

Función Ajax para ejecutar petición al controlador en java:

```
function consultaPerfil(id_author){
$.ajax({
    url: "consultarDatosPerfilAuthor.html",
    type: "GET",
    dataType: "html",
    data:"id_author="+id_author,
    cache: false,
    contentType: false,
    processData: false,
        success : function(response) {
            PrintPerfil(response);

        },
        error : function(e) {
            console.log("ERROR: ", e);
            display(e);
        },
        done : function(e) {
            console.log("DONE");
        }
    });
```

Función en el controlador para realizar consultas necesarias de información:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/consultarDatosPerfilAuthor", method = { RequestMethod.GET, RequestMethod.POST })
public @ResponseBody String consultarDatosPerfilAuthor(HttpServletRequest request) {

    int author = Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("id_author"));

    String jsonCompleto = hibernateTransations.consultarDatosProfile(author);

    return jsonCompleto;
}
```

Función que consulta la información necesaria a mostrar en el popOver y retornar un string/json:

```
public static String consultarDatosProfile(int IdAccount) {

    Session session = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().openSession();
    Object [] datos;
    String sentenciaSQL = "Select a.name,a.last_name,a.email,a.birth_date,a.number_phone,p.reputation,p.photo FROM Account a,Profile p Where        p.profile_account = a.id_account and a.id_account = ?";

    try{

        session.beginTransaction();
        Query query = session.createQuery(sentenciaSQL);            
        query.setParameter(0,IdAccount);
        List<Object[]> results = query.getResultList();
        datos=results.get(0);
        String datosProfile = "[{\"nombre_author\":\""+ datos[0] + " " + datos[1] + "\"}]";

        return datosProfile;


    }catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("Error en el metodo consultarProfile - " + e.getMessage());
        return null;
    }finally {
        session.disconnect();
    }

}
```

Función JavaScript que recibe la información a mostrar en el popOver #popoverUser1:

```
function PrintPerfil(data){
    dato=JSON.parse(data);

    dst='<p align="center">' +dato[0].nombre_author+'</p>'+
    '<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-star" style="color:blue"></span>';


    $('#popoverUser1').popover({
            title:dst,
            content : "<strom>Tel: </strom><p>"+dato[0].nombre_author+"</p>",
            html: true
        });
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Prueba a establecer la propiedad `trigger` con el valor `'manual'` en lugar del varlor `'click'` en la función popover.

La razón es que estás mostrando el popover enlazando manualmente el evento que debe dispararla: `onclick="consultaPerfil(this.name)"`

```
$('#popoverUser1').popover({
            trigger: 'manual',
            title:dst,
            content : "<strom>Tel: </strom><p>"+dato[0].nombre_author+"</p>",
            html: true
        });
```

Comment: hola, gracias por tu respuesta, pero no me funciono tu solución.